# stateParam setting Scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ok so in stateParam i understand how to set a number like

/new/123432

```
$stateProvider
    .state('contacts', {
        url: "/new/:portfolioId",
        templateUrl: 'contacts.html',
        controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
          console.log(portfolioId)
          $scope.portfolioId = randomString(10);
           $scope.portfolioId = $stateParams.portfolioId;
        }
    })
```

And Html:

```
<a ui-sref="contacts({ portfolioId : 123432})">New (query string)</a>
```

BUT In the Html i dont want portfolioId to be equal to 123432 so i comes out like /new/123456 i want it to be equal to a scope... For example this:

```
$scope.something = 98780
```

How do we do that... I already tried doing this but failed:

```
<a ui-sref="contacts({ portfolioId : something})">New (query string)</a>
```

The above code when clicked gives me this:
http://run.plnkr.co/lPbkszt7DMxDSGji/#/new/

It dosent get the additonal info at the end...

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/FB7dyfx2W17GYddvwI9m?p=preview

Comment: How did it fail? What is the error? Can you reproduce in a demo?

Comment: No it didnt give me any error it just says /new/  I will get a plunker in one seocnd.. Just updated it with plunker.. Look at the url.. it just says /new/

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the code you posted. This is not how $stateParams should work?

Comment: Look at the plunker @fbid I explained to ecleranes it just says /new/

Comment: I dont understand what you want. you want the url to look how exactly like this /new/123432? or you dont want to show the id?

Comment: I want to show the id. But by scope.. Like saying $scope.something = 123432 and then do contacts{{portfolio id : something}}  but that dosent work as mentioned above @Sudakatux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the property on the wrong controller:

```
app.controller('homeCtrl', ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.something = randomString(10);
}])
```

I see this now: `href="#/new/L96T2oc5SP`